# Bootstrap nav links with images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

We have added images to the links in navigation bar.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/148x50"/><br/>Link1</a>
        </li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/148x50"/><br/>Link2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Then we have centered the nav by:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-nav {
        float:none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the text is not center under links:

Please see

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/2004/

Any comments ?!

Are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is centered text, just add this to the CSS:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/2006/

This has the unfortunate consequence of also centering the images, which may or may not be what you want (I think it looks fine that way however).

Another more involved option would be to add a text div with a width fixed to image size: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/2007/

Comment: I have added the css in the media, so the images will not be centered when menu collapses. http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/2009/. That was what I was looking for. Thanks!